# Application Insights starttrackevent stopstrackevent across pages in a single session

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am having trouble tracking down documentation on this, so hoping someone knows as I am not able to get application insights to capture telemetry on starttrackevent and stopstrackevent across pages. This is an asp.net mvc application, so SPA is not in play here.

I am worried I may be doing something incorrectly, however the likely case is it doesn't support it.

Flow:

- user hits site for the first time
- user does action that triggers startTrackEvent("eventName");
- user navigates to a new page
- user does action that triggers stopTrackEvent("eventName");

-- from the appInsights readme
https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/README.md

`appInsights.startTrackEvent("event");`

`appInsights.stopTrackEvent("event", null, {customProp1: "some value"});`

Comment: In my opinion, `telemetryClient.trackEvent()` is a manual action, or in other words, I don't know how to make this method track event automatically, so it can't be set to start or stop. Did I misunderstand in some place?

Comment: Hi @Tiny, there is a trackEvent of course, but there are also startTrackEvent and stopTrackEvent which has the added benefit of duration being tracked.

Can be found here on the readme
https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not per documentation, but via testing, can confirm that when a new page loads, appInsights will not persist start/stoptrackevent.